# How to set base url for all controllers in micronaut ? through application.yml or any configuration

Tags: kotlin, jvm, micronaut

How to set base url for all controllers

```
 @Controller("/api/hello")
class HelloController{

    @Get("/greet")
   fun greet(){

   }
}
```

Instead of writing /api on each controller is there a way to write it as base url in configuration for all rest controller endpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure once [RouteBuilder.UriNamingStrategy](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/api/io/micronaut/web/router/RouteBuilder.UriNamingStrategy.html) (default implementation [HyphenatedUriNamingStrategy](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.0.RC1/api/io/micronaut/web/router/naming/HyphenatedUriNamingStrategy.html))

1. add some custom property **micronaut.context-path**, `application.yml`:

```yaml
micronaut:
  context-path: /someApiPath
```

2. create `ConfigurableUriNamingStrategy` and extend `HyphenatedUriNamingStrategy` :

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Replaces(HyphenatedUriNamingStrategy::class)
class ConfigurableUriNamingStrategy : HyphenatedUriNamingStrategy() {
    
    @Value("\${micronaut.context-path}")
    var contextPath: String? = null

    override fun resolveUri(type: Class<*>?): String {
        return contextPath ?: "" + super.resolveUri(type)
    }

    override fun resolveUri(beanDefinition: BeanDefinition<*>?): String {
        return contextPath ?: "" + super.resolveUri(beanDefinition)
    }

    override fun resolveUri(property: String?): String {
        return contextPath ?: "" + super.resolveUri(property)
    }

    override fun resolveUri(type: Class<*>?, id: PropertyConvention?): String {
        return contextPath ?: "" + super.resolveUri(type, id)
    }
}
```

This configurations will be applied for all controllers,
for your `HelloController` URI path will be `/someApiPath/greet`, if the property `micronaut.context-path` is missing then `/greet`:

```kotlin
@Controller
class HelloController {

   @Get("/greet")
   fun greet(){

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No such feature is available off the shelf at the moment 
have to specify custom properties in application.yml and refer them from controller

eg:

```
@Controller(“${my.config:/api}/foo”))
```